# C# - Reorganize string of text

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of text: AB CD EF GH

I want to invert the text, so it looks like this: GH EF CD AB

So, AB CD EF GH will become GH EF CD AB

Comment: Please post some code and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if it's only spaces separating the parts, you can do that reasonably easily:

```
string reversed = string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Reverse());
```

In .NET 3.5 you'd need an extra call to ToArray due to string.Join not having the same overloads at .NET 4:

```
string reversed = string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Reverse().ToArray());
```

It can be done more efficiently using `Array.Reverse` to reverse the split array in-place:

```
string[] parts = text.Split(' ');
Array.Reverse(parts);
string reversed = string.Join(" ", parts);
```

... but whether the difference will be *significant* or not is more doubtful :)

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `string[] parts = text.Split(' ');` as string.split returns an array ?

Comment: Glad I could help the famous Jon Skeet! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Join(" ",("AB CD EF GH".Split(' ').Reverse()))
```

Basically: Split your input string on the space, so that you have an array of "AB", "CD", "EF" and "GH". Then Reverse that array, and join the pieces of the array together as a string again, using the space character as glue.

- [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)
- [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)
- [Enumerable.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split into an array of strings (look at string.Split), use Array.Reverse

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx

then join the resulting string with spaces again (string.Join).

Answer (score 0):

Split it into an array, reverse the array, and join it:

```
string.Join(" ", "AB CD EF GH".Split(' ').Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet uses System (for StringSplitOptions) and System.Linq (for Reverse())

```
string input = "AB CD EF GH";
```

this array contains all word separators like spaces, commas, dots and so on.

```
var wordSeparators = new string[] { " " };
```

The [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) method used for split string in words.
[StringSplitOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netcore-3.1) is used to remove all empty strings that may occur between two word separators (like double space or comma and space).

```
var words = input.Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then you just need to [reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netcore-3.1) words order and join them into single string using [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) method.

```
var result = string.Join(" ", words.Reverse());
```